# Typescript embedded generic types do not follow the generic parameters properly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have created a generic Image interface, then when I need to use some of those values in another generic interface using the same generic parameter, Typescript does not seem to be able to infer the types properly. It seems like Typescript tries to take every option with the "|" operator.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
type ImageType = "require" | "uri";

interface Common<T extends ImageType> {
    type: T;
    other?: string;
    stuff?: string;
}
interface Require extends Common<"require"> {
    source: number;
    mime: string;
}
interface URI extends Common<"uri"> {
    source: string;
    mime?: string;
}
type Image<T extends ImageType> =
      T extends "require" ? Require
    : T extends "uri" ? URI
    : Common<T>;

interface Custom<T extends ImageType> {
    type: Image<T>["type"];
    source?: Image<T>["source"];
    mime: Image<T>["mime"];
    other?: string;
    stuff?: string;
}

const example0 = (image: Image<ImageType>) => "do something";
const exemple1 = (custom: Custom<ImageType>) => custom.source &&
    example0({type: custom.type, source: custom.source, mime: custom.mime})
```

Which Produced at the last line:
(I have voluntarily the types of `Custom<ImageType>` & `Image<ImageType>` because I want any type of images in these example)

```
Argument of type '{ type: ImageType; source: string | number; mime: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Require | URI'.
  Type '{ type: ImageType; source: string | number; mime: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'URI'.
    Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: `Common<T extends ImageType>` this doesn't make any sense. How can you extend from a string literal type? I think it should be simply `type: ImageType` within the Common interface definition.

Comment: Well you can extend string literals in generic types to limit the possible strings. Try the following:
```ts
type options = "a" | "b" | "c";
interface Example<T extends options> {
    type: T;
}
const test: Example<"d"> = {type: "d"}
```
My point here is to limit the common interface generic parameters to `"require" | "uri"`. Now I could remove the generics for the Common interface and keep it for the Custom one but it would not resolve my problem.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now, you're using the generic limited to the subset of strings. The typescript `extends` keyword is slightly misleading in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting those errors because essentially your `Custom<ImageType>` is resolving down to -

```
{
    type: ImageType;
    source?: string | number | undefined;
    mime: string | undefined;
    other?: string;
    stuff?: string;
}
```

Now you are trying to assign that type to `Image<ImageType>` which resolves to `Require|URI` and your `Custom<ImageType>` is not assignable to `Require|URI`.